# What happens to 'this' when it goes into Object.map

Tags: reactjs

Does anyone know what happened to 'this'?

```
    console.log('check 1', this) //{activateLasers: ƒ, …}
    Object.keys(modelData).forEach(function(key, index1) {
    console.log('check 2', this) //undefined
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The context of this changes inside map.

Array.prototype.map() takes a second argument to set what this refers to in the mapping function.

You can explicitly pass it to the map function to preserve the context.

```
array.map(function(i) {
  ...
} , this)
```

In your case

```
array.forEach(function(key, i) {
    ....
}, this)
```

Alternatively, you can use an ES6 arrow function to automatically preserve the current this context

```
array.map((i) => {
  ...
})
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you're writing code in strict mode. `this` is undefined because that's how the language works.

`this` in javascript is a syntactic construct. When you call a class or object method you usually do it in a way that looks like `obj.method()`. The language sees the syntactic pattern with the `.` and `()` and makes `this` obj inside `method`. If you ever don't see that pattern, (and are not using an `=>` function, it should be a good cue that this might be `undefined` or `window`.